# Please help me understand the output of this assertMultiLineEqual failure

Tags: python, testing

This is the output from a failed assertMultiLineEqual:

```
- </group></row></resultset>+ </group></row></resultset>
?                           +
```

I have no idea what this means and why its complaining about it being different.  My script generates an XML string and I want to compare it to the contents of an XML file.  I took the exact string that is outputted and made it the file contents, and its complaining about this last line.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of the strings ends with a newline character, and the other doesn't.

Comment: i think this is basically correct.  I ran strip() on both and now the test passes, thanks!

Comment: @Peter, you're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).